# Problem on multiplicative function

Tags: induction, contest-math, proof-explanation

This is the excerpt from the book "Putnam and Beyond". I have some difficulties with understang some moments os the solution. Please help.

[image]
[image]

1) Why do the author consider exactly this type of number, namely $2^r(2m+1)$?

2) How did the author conclude that $2^r(2m+1)$ is either $k,k+1,k+2$ or $k+3$?

3) If $k>3$ why both $2^r$ and $2m+1$ are strictly less than $k$?

4) How did they combine monotonicity and fact to conclude that $f(l)=l$ on the interval?

In my opinion, the solution is quite unclear.

Can anyone please answer to my questions in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Every even positive integer which is not a power of $2$ can be written uniquely in the form $2^r(2m+1)$ where $m,r>0$. (In fact every positive integer can be written in this form for $m,r\geq 0$; if $r=0$ then the integer is odd and if $m=0$ it is a power of $2$.)

(If you mean "why did the author consider numbers that are even but not powers of $2$?", they were actually looking for a number which is a nontrivial product of two coprime integers, so that you can reduce it to smaller numbers in a helpful way. It's just that one easy way to do this is to require one number to be a power of $2$ and the other to be odd; this happens sufficiently often that you don't lose much by looking for that particular form.)

2) If $k$ and $k+2$ are even, they can't both be powers of $2$ since they aren't $2$ and $4$. So one of them will work. Otherwise one of $k+1$ and $k+3$ works for the same reason.

3) $2^r\geq 2$, so $2m+1\leq (k+3)/2^r\leq (k+3)/2< k$. Similarly since $2m+1\geq 3$, $2^r\leq (k+3)/3<k$.

4) Since the function is strictly increasing and takes integers to integers, $f(n+1)\geq f(n)+1$ for every $n$. It follows that $f(n+a)\geq f(n)+a$ for every $a,n$. Since $f(2)=2$, $f(l)\geq f(2)+l-2=l$ for every $l$. If $f(l)> l$ for any $l<2^r(2m+1)$ then we would have $f(2^r(2m+1))\geq f(l)+2^r(2m+1)-l>2^r(2m+1)$. This isn't true, so we must have $f(l)=l$ for all $l\leq 2^r(2m+1)$.

Comment: 2) What about $k+4, \ k+5,..$? Why the author considers only $k,k+1,k+2,k+3$?

Comment: Because you're just looking for the next $k$ of the required form, and there always will be one in $k,k+1,k+2,k+3$.

Comment: Of course, there will be others further along too. But you don't want to use one of those, because part 3) will go wrong.

Comment: What does mean "the next $k$ of the required form"? Why the author exclude number bigger than $k+3$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the next *number* of the required form. So the smallest $j\geq k$ which is even but not a power of $2$. This will never be bigger than $k+3$.

Comment: Exactly! That's i would like to understand. Why it will never be bigger than $k+3$?

Comment: That's point 2) above. The only way it could go wrong is if the two even numbers among $k,...,k+3$ are both powers of $2$. But you can't have two powers of $2$ that close together (and both $>3$).

Comment: Many thanks for such clear answer! You have helped me to grasp this interesting problem from Putnam. I'll mark your answer as the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68526/discussion-between-rfz-and-especially-lime).